# Using wp_list_authors to display Contributors Only

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to output a list of Users who have the role of Contributor so I can display all the contributors on a page with some of their attributes (name, company, title, bio, photo etc.)

I have the following function in my theme:

```
function my_text_after_content() {
if(is_page(400)) {
wp_list_authors( array(
    'show_fullname' => 1,
    'optioncount'   => 1,
    'orderby'       => 'post_count',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'html'          => 0
) );
} };
```

This lists out all the authors in my theme but I am having a hard time limiting it to contributors. Any advice on how best to do this and be able to call in their other parameters would be helpful.

Comment: Please add the results you are getting and an example of the results you wish to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first get list of not Contributors, then exclude their IDs from list

```
$users = get_users(['role__not_in' => ['Contributor']]);
foreach( $users as $user ){
    $ids[] = $user->ID;
}
if(is_page(400)) {
    wp_list_authors( array(
        'show_fullname' => 1,
        'optioncount'   => 1,
        'orderby'       => 'post_count',
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'html'          => 0,
        'exclude'       => $ids
    ) );
} };
```

either this has to work as well

```
$users = get_users(['role__in' => ['Contributor']]);
foreach( $users as $user ){
    $ids[] = $user->ID;
}
if(is_page(400)) {
    wp_list_authors( array(
        'show_fullname' => 1,
        'optioncount'   => 1,
        'orderby'       => 'post_count',
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'html'          => 0,
        'include'       => $ids
    ) );
} };
```

Comment: Ignore that last comment. This works for me! Thank you!